# Set custom attribute to a DOM element in React v15.5.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently in my render method I have something like this

```
<h1 customAttibute="customValue" className="classValue">This h1</h1>
```

This is rendered in my browser as this

```
<h1 class="classValue">This h1</h1>
```

This is because React 15 doesn't seem to support custom attributes

Annoyingly it looks like in React v16 this issue is resolved but upgrading to React 16 is not an option for me at this stage - https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html

Is there anyway I can add a custom attribute to my element, setAttribute maybe? If anyone can point me in the right direction on how to do that or some documentation that would be amazing

Comment: Have you tried using data-attributes?

Comment: Hey @ParnabSanyal - No as this wouldn't work for my case, I have CSS that is already defined that should style the h1 from the custom attribute and I have no access to the CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a callback ref.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.element = null;
    this.setElementRef = (element) => {
      this.element = element;
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.element.setAttribute("customattribute", "foo bar");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.setElementRef} className="classValue">
        Hello world!
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can read more about it [on React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs), though some of the information is newer than React 15.5.4 (such as `React.createRef`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ref` to get a reference to the DOM element along with `setAttribute`, in `componenDidMount`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.myRef.current.setAttribute('customAttibute', 'customValue')
}

render() {
    return <h1 ref={this.myRef} className="classValue">This h1</h1>;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so .. I think React.createRef() is introduced in React 16 ---> https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html .. it does look like there is a different call back so I will investigate